# How to track deployed NextJS app on New Relic?

Tags: next.js, firebase-hosting, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I am trying to measure the performance of my deployed NextJS app on New Relic. But New Relic is not able to consume information from my deployed NextJS app which has been deployed on Firebase-hosting. It consumes information when the app is running locally but not when it's deployed. Can anyone help, please?

```
"use strict";
/**
 * New Relic agent configuration.
 *
 * See lib/config/default.js in the agent distribution for a more complete
 * description of configuration variables and their potential values.
 */

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";

exports.config = {
  /**
   * Array of application names.
   */
  app_name: [isProd? "prod_app_name" : "local_app_name"],
  /**
   * Your New Relic license key.
   */
  license_key: isProd ? "prod_license_key" : "local_license_key",
  /**
   * This setting controls distributed tracing.
   * Distributed tracing lets you see the path that a request takes through your
   * distributed system. Enabling distributed tracing changes the behavior of some
   * New Relic features, so carefully consult the transition guide before you enable
   * this feature: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/transition-guide-distributed-tracing
   * Default is true.
   */
  distributed_tracing: {
    /**
     * Enables/disables distributed tracing.
     *
     * @env NEW_RELIC_DISTRIBUTED_TRACING_ENABLED
     */
    enabled: true,
  },
  logging: {
    /**
     * Level at which to log. 'trace' is most useful to New Relic when diagnosing
     * issues with the agent, 'info' and higher will impose the least overhead on
     * production applications.
     */
    level: "info",
  },
  application_logging: {
    forwarding: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  },
  /**
   * When true, all request headers except for those listed in attributes.exclude
   * will be captured for all traces, unless otherwise specified in a destination's
   * attributes include/exclude lists.
   */
  allow_all_headers: true,
  attributes: {
    /**
     * Prefix of attributes to exclude from all destinations. Allows * as wildcard
     * at end.
     *
     * NOTE: If excluding headers, they must be in camelCase form to be filtered.
     *
     * @env NEW_RELIC_ATTRIBUTES_EXCLUDE
     */
    exclude: [
      "request.headers.cookie",
      "request.headers.authorization",
      "request.headers.proxyAuthorization",
      "request.headers.setCookie*",
      "request.headers.x*",
      "response.headers.cookie",
      "response.headers.authorization",
      "response.headers.proxyAuthorization",
      "response.headers.setCookie*",
      "response.headers.x*",
    ],
  },
};
```

Above is my newrelic.js code.